# Kaa Custom Transport

Tags: kaa

I am trying to implement CoAP as my custom transport protocol for Kaa platform. I've done customization guide [creating custom transport](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Creating+custom+transport) step by step, but in the last part (Transport provisioning), it seems that some config files should be created automatically but I can't find any ***.config** file related to my implemented CoAP class in *server/transports* package. Neither in */kaa/server* nor in */etc/conf* sub-folders. Any idea about what should I do?
This attached image show how my implementation developed ‒ [project hierarchic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKrnU.png).

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant for you:

First of all, I don't see in your project neither implementation of [transport configuration schema](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Creating+custom+transport#Creatingcustomtransport-Transportconfigurationschema) nor [transport descriptor](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Creating+custom+transport#Creatingcustomtransport-Transportdescriptorimplementation). Follow this steps:

1. Create avro schema that defines configuration parameters for the
   transport and compile one with avro maven plugin (look how this done
   for [tcp transport](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/server/transports/tcp/config)).
2. Once you've done with schema, implement the transport descriptor in     order to Kaa node can look up your custom transport.

Secondary, the config file for you custom transport you should create manually. The example of config files for tcp and http located in *server/node/src/main/resources* both for operation and bootstrap servers.

Finally, compile and package your custom transport project into jar artifacts (two jars ‒ config classes and classes related to CoAP transport). Put this jars to */usr/lib/kaa-node/lib* on your server, config files ‒ */usr/lib/kaa-node/conf*. After that restart the node and enjoy a newly created transport for CoAP.